# Not able to install "readxl" package into R version 3.3.1

Tags: r, installation

I was trying to load the package "readxl" however, I got an error message saying "package ‘readxl’ was built under R version 3.3.3 "

I also tried to install the package"installr" for R update icon to be shown on the top of R studio but received the same error saying "package ‘installr’ was built under R version 3.3.3". Please help me fix this issue. Else please advise an alternate way to import xlsx or xls file into R.

Comment: That's not an error, it's just a message.

Comment: ohh my bad. Thanks for the correction

Comment: You should either update R to 3.3.3 (maintenance version of 3.3.x series) or 3.4.0 (latest version). If this is not possible, you can sift through MS R open's CRAN archive to find a suitable date. For example, this one will work: https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2016-07-31/.

Answer (score 0):

```
install.packages("openxlsx")
library(openxlsx)
```

now to read your xlsx file,

```
file <- read.xlsx("your_file_directory", )
```

Comment: Thanks but for this I need java to be installed on my system. I don't have Java..any other alternative sir?

Comment: Try the edit. Also the output you are getting is not an error, it is just a warning. Make sure you have the version been mentioned in the warning or above.